# How to create list filter

Tags: java

In my List, I want to ignore certain entries(create list filter), by ignore I mean remove. If my list contains A to Z String elements, let say I want to remove B, F and Z.

How would I do this with var args, arbitrary number of elements to be removed from the list?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [`List#removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
List<String> alphabet = new ArrayList<String>();
alphabet.add("A");
alphabet.add("B");
alphabet.add("C");
alphabet.add("D");
alphabet.add("E");
alphabet.add("F");
alphabet.add("G");
// Etc..
List<String> toRemove = Arrays.asList("B", "F"); // Takes varargs!

alphabet.removeAll(toRemove);

System.out.println(alphabet); // A, C, D, E, G
```

Comment: what about building the alphabet with new ArrayList<String>(asList("A","B"...)) ? (the copy is not expensive), or if you can use guava Lists.newArrayList("A", "B",...)

Comment: @Sylvian: That's up to the OP. The question was not about building. As long as nothing explicitly is mentioned, standard Java SE API is assumed. True, Guava is great, but I can't answer a Guava based solution from top of head. You're free to do so as long as a reasonable Java SE API based answer is given/pointed. The OP might have reasons to not use/prefer "3rd party" API's.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point of view, thanks for the explanation. Next time I answer the question, I will firstly think with standard API (except if mentionned)

Answer (score 3):

Using guava

```
final Iterable<String> filtered = Iterables.removeIf(asList("A","B","C", "Z"), new Predicate<String>(){
    public boolean apply(final String element){
       // your filter, eg
       return element.equals("A");
    )
}
```

Comment: `contains` should be `equals` regarding the question.

Answer (score 1):

Quick guess (using varargs):

```
void removeFromList(List<Object> list, Object ... filterElements){
  for(Object elm:filterElements){
    while(list.remove(elm));
  }
}
```